# How to make input field and the modal to have same width and add padding

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-selectors

I am using `antd` picker for selecting ranges.. Right now the selected range is not fitting inside the input box. How can I make the input field width and calendar width same so that the selected dates will fit just fine. Also I would like to add padding to the calendar on all the sides of it. The width of the input and the calendar should be same to fit the content after selection something shown below in the image

https://codesandbox.io/s/ant-rangepicker-6gmz85?file=/src/styles.scss

```
.App{
  width: 280px; 
  height: 500px;
}
.custom-datepicker {
  .ant-picker-active-bar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Component

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.scss";
import { DatePicker } from "antd";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";

const { RangePicker } = DatePicker;

export default function Working() {
  return (
    <RangePicker
      className="custom-datepicker"
      dropdownClassName="custom-datepicker-dropdown"
      separator={<>-</>}
      format="DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss"
    />
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
.App{
  width: 350px; 
  height: 500px;
}
.custom-datepicker {
  .ant-picker-active-bar {
    display: none;
  }
}

.custom-datepicker-dropdown {
  .ant-picker-panel-container {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    .ant-picker-panels {
      flex: 1;
      display: flex;
      .ant-picker-panel:not(:first-child) {
        display: none;
      }
      :first-child {
        button.ant-picker-header-next-btn {
          visibility: visible !important;
        }
      }
    }
    .ant-picker-panel {
      flex: 1;
      display: flex;
      border: none;
      .ant-picker-date-panel {
        width: auto;
        .ant-picker-header{
          border-bottom: none;
        }
        .ant-picker-body {
          display: flex;
          place-content: center;
          padding: 10px 10px;
          .ant-picker-content {
            tr td:nth-child(7) {
              background-color: grey;
            }
            .ant-picker-cell {
              &.ant-picker-cell-in-view {
                &.ant-picker-cell-today {
                  .ant-picker-cell-inner {
                    &::before {
                      border: green;
                      border-radius: 50%;
                    }
                  }
                }
                &.ant-picker-cell-range-start {
                  .ant-picker-cell-inner {
                    border-top-left-radius: 32px;
                    border-bottom-left-radius: 32px;
                    background-color: green;
                  }
                  &:not(.ant-picker-cell-range-start-single) {
                    &::before {
                      background-color: green;
                    }
                  }
                }
                &.ant-picker-cell-range-end {
                  .ant-picker-cell-inner {
                    border-top-right-radius: 32px;
                    border-bottom-right-radius: 32px;
                    background-color: green;
                  }
                  &:not(.ant-picker-cell-range-end-single) {
                    &::before {
                      background-color: green;
                    }
                  }
                }
                &.ant-picker-cell-in-range {
                  &::before {
                    background-color: lightblue;
                  }
                  .ant-picker-cell-inner {
                    color: blue;
                  }
                }
                &.ant-picker-cell-selected {
                  .ant-picker-cell-inner {
                       background-color: green;
                 }                
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

try this one.

Comment: Thank you, after adding your css, the footer is going to the next section, instead of staying at the bottom. Can you please check this?https://codesandbox.io/s/ant-rangepicker-6gmz85?file=/src/Working.tsx

Comment: try editing in code sandbox and inspect the layout css classes try to edit appropriate class you can fix footer issue.